# Imitiating cURL with Java

Tags: java, curl, get, httprequest

I'd like to  obtain a content of a page with Java (java 7 to be precise).
When I enter that site with browser what I get is modal/popup about cookies, personalized ads etc and the same happens when I use for example:

```
URL url = new URL(v1.getUrl());
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("GET");
InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
```

By accident I found out that with `cURL` in Bash i get the "correct" output of the site. With
`curl URL` i get response without this modal. The same thing happens when I use `curl` from Java code:

`ArticleExtractor.getInstance().getText(new InputStreamReader(new ProcessBuilder(("curl "+url).split(" ")).start().getInputStream()))`.

Is there any way not to use `curl` and get the same outcome in Java?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line after your `con.setRequestMethod()`.

```
con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "curl/7.65.0");
```

If that works, it means that the HTTP server is serving different content to `curl` vs other browsers.